# How fast does the coprime probability converge to $6/\pi^2$?

Tags: limits, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-mathematics, totient-function

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) that the probability that two positive integers are coprime is $6/\pi^2$. This is an amazing result. I wanted to see experimentally how the probability converges to $6/\pi^2$, but I found that the sequence converges terribly slow, and I would not believe that it converges unless I didn't know a proof that it actually does.

Let $a(n)$ be the number of pairs $1 \leq a,b \leq n$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$. The "probability" in question is defined as a [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) here by
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a(n)/n^2.$$
It evaluates to $6/\pi^2$. For computations it should be useful to have the formula
$$a(n) = 1 + 2 \sum_{a=2}^{n} \varphi(a),$$
where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient function](https://%7B311c74d0-7f05-45c9-ac95-f3367c6020e9%7D). I wrote a little program that computes the values of $a(n)/n^2$, or actually $n \sqrt{6/a(n)}$ since that value should converge to $\pi$, and I would like to see the digits of $\pi$ coming out. Here is a typical excerpt from the sequence (for $10000 \leq n \leq 10005$):

```
3.141534239016629
3.141342469859083
3.14148445699957
3.14135604503421
3.1414222455373713
3.14148184775969
```

The sequence "wiggles" and takes "forever" to get close to `3.14159...` . Why is that? More precisely:

1. What is the "convergence speed" of that sequence? This would be formalized with the [order of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence).
2. If $d \geq 1$, is there some $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ the number $n \sqrt{6/a(n)}$ has the first $d$ digits of $\pi$? For example, is this true for $d=4$, so that we have `3.1415...` from some point on? Numerical experiments suggest that this indeed the case, but $n_0$ is very large.
3. A bit more broader: can we adjust the sequence slightly, or at least find a different sequence related to the coprimality of integers, that converges to $\pi$ more fast?

Comment: Well, we know $\sum_{a\leq n}\varphi(a)=3\left(\frac{n}\pi\right)^2+\Delta$
with $\lvert\Delta\rvert<\frac12n\log n+(\frac12\gamma+\frac58)n+1$ so you can use this to bound interval of $\pi$.  (Better asymptotic error bounds exist, e.g. $O(x(\log x)^{2/3}(\log\log x)^{4/3})$ but probably not as useful for $n$ this low).  We could choose to sum $\sum_{m\leq n}\phi(pm)$ or $\sum_{m\leq n}\phi(pm-k)$ for $k=1,\dots,p-1$ instead but I'm not sure about the gain.  Maybe a similar method based on $\zeta(4)$ would give better result?

Comment: Apparently the best know asymptotic is $a(n)=6/\pi^2 x^2 +O( x(\log x)^{2/3}(\log\log x)^{4/3} )$ and the error term can't be much smaller than that because when $n$ is prime, $a(n)-a(n-1)=2p-2$.